# SQL Truncation Error for no reason

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, truncation

We have some code that has started throwing an error in the past day.  The code has not changed for months.  The error message is:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

The SQL statement is:

```
UPDATE TUP
SET insured_state_cd = UTCA.state_province_cd
FROM #TEMP_UAFR_POLICY TUP
    JOIN dbo.UVW_THIRDS UT ON
        TUP.prim_owner_third_id = UT.third_id
    JOIN dbo.UVW_THIRDS_CONTACTS_ADDRESSES UTCA ON
        UT.primary_address_id = UTCA.address_id
    JOIN dbo.UVW_INTERNATIONAL_COUNTRY UIC ON
        UTCA.country_cd = UIC.country_cd
```

Now, I will tell you that yes, the UTCA.state_province_cd column is larger than the insured_state_cd column.  We know this is not a good thing, but our testing process will require a minimum of a month to get the change approved and into production.  We really need to figure out the cause of this issue.

We checked the UTCA table and no record has a length of more than 2, which is the size of the column in the TUP table.  Since it is a CHAR type, we also checked the binary values of the table to ensure it wasn't a carriage return or some other hidden character.

To add to the mystery, this code works:

```
UPDATE TUP
SET insured_state_cd = UTCA.state_province_cd
FROM #TEMP_UAFR_POLICY TUP
    JOIN dbo.UVW_THIRDS UT ON
        TUP.prim_owner_third_id = UT.third_id
    JOIN dbo.UVW_THIRDS_CONTACTS_ADDRESSES UTCA ON
        UT.primary_address_id = UTCA.address_id
    JOIN dbo.UVW_INTERNATIONAL_COUNTRY UIC ON
        UTCA.country_cd = UIC.country_cd
WHERE UTCA.state_province_cd IN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT UTCA2.state_province_cd 
            FROM dbo.UVW_THIRDS_CONTACTS_ADDRESSES UTCA2)
```

As you can see, the second code is the same as the first, it basically just checks does 1=1?  Also, the code works on our development server as is, in the original form.  We literally backed up the db's, restored to dev, ran the code and it works.

Comment: If you only want the first two characters from UTCA.state_province_cd, how about `SET insured_state_cd = LEFT(UTCA.state_province_cd, 2) ...`? And are the dev and production DBs running the *exact* same version of SQL Server?

Comment: Here's a *crazy* idea - why not create the #temp table so that its columns and data types actually match the source tables? I can't fathom why increasing the length of a #temp table definition would take any time at all to approve and deploy. If that takes a month then you have bigger problems that string truncation.

Comment: Also, did you check the values that result from the join, or ***all*** values in the table? SQL Server can optimize things in different orders, where the length is checked *before* the filter on one server, and the length is checked *after* the filter on the other.

Comment: did anyone add a trigger to cause other SQL to fire other than this?

Comment: Thanks for your sarcasm, it is my favorite thing to see after having fun with this issue.  I cannot change the code testing or release process.  This is just 1 statement in a large SP which is used for financial processes so very through testing is needed to change it.

Comment: @Aaron, There are values in the table which could cause a truncation error, but none of them are used.  Perhaps this could be the cause though I'm not sure why it decided to pop up now...  I will look into this further.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy, no triggers.  There are a few on some of the tables in the query, but none on the temp table.

Comment: "none of them are used" - what does this mean? I think you are reading the query from top to bottom logically, and assuming that the operations in the query occur in the order you wrote them. If SQL Server tries to validate the length before any filters have applied to that table, then it doesn't matter that those values don't actually end up in the end result.

Comment: For grins post your code where you checked the UTCA table and no record has a length of more than 2.  And that is not exactly a 1=1 - I suspect you have a changed execution plan

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you used LEN(column) to check the data? That will tell you the number of characters and not include any white space. I have a feeling the white space is why it's erroring out. Try trimming off the white space.

```
UPDATE TUP
SET insured_state_cd = RTRIM(LTRIM(UTCA.state_province_cd))
FROM #TEMP_UAFR_POLICY TUP
    JOIN dbo.UVW_THIRDS UT ON
        TUP.prim_owner_third_id = UT.third_id
    JOIN dbo.UVW_THIRDS_CONTACTS_ADDRESSES UTCA ON
        UT.primary_address_id = UTCA.address_id
    JOIN dbo.UVW_INTERNATIONAL_COUNTRY UIC ON
        UTCA.country_cd = UIC.country_c
```

Comment: Of course it can be fixed by making the field lengths match or by trimming, unfortunately, due to the crazy process for code changes, I cannot change this until a release.  The process worked fine for many years and just broke in the past day.  Nothing has changed as far as schema or settings, obviously data changes all the time, but nothing else has changed in the timeframe I'm working with.

Comment: Did you try SELECT UTCA.state_province_cd FROM UTCA WHERE DATALENGTH(CAST(UTCA.state_province_cd AS VARCHAR(5)) > 2? Does it return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you say raises any red flags or has a (to me) obvious answer. Here are some things I’d look into (which you may have already done).

You say “CHAR” type.  CHAR, or VARCHAR? Makes we wonder about leading and/or trailing spaces. (Any nvarchars in there? How about varchar(max)? ) It’d help to see the table definitions of both #TEMP_UAFR_POLICY and UVW_THIRDS_CONTACTS_ADDRESSES.

You’ve used both the LEN() *and* DATALENGTH() functions to check the columns, yes?

“Backed up on production and restored on development” combined with #tempdbs reminds me of a time we installed a SQL with a code page (or whatever) *different* from all our other SQL installations. The databases all worked the same, but the system databases—most notably tempdb—were operating under different assumptions, and that caused some fairly subtle problems. Maybe something’s going on there?

Check and compare versions and editions, down to the service pack, of SQL between both environments.

Comment: Good ideas, but unfortunately I didn't find anything here.  They are char(2) and char(5).  Since they are CHAR, they return a datalength = the length of the field always.  I checked tempdb and it has the same settings, including collation on both servers.  Both are same sp and patch level.